# How to find semantic orientation of a bigram and a list of words with R

Tags: r, text-mining

I am using this paper [Finding Semantic Orientation of Reviews](https://www.ijsr.net/archive/v5i2/NOV161734.pdf)  to determine semantic orientation between a phrase and a list of words using pointwize mutual information.

```
For example : PMI(phrase, {"excellent", "Good"}).
```

My question is should I compute PMI for every word composing the phrase or using the phrase as a global entity?

Comment: I think this not a question about R itself but belongs in the Crossvalidated forum